# onmouseover javascript function not linking?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the opacity of a divider when the user hovers over it.
This is what I have so far.

Here is the script being linked in the head.

```
<head>
    <link href="styling/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styling/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="timeline.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is the divider I want to change

```
<div onmouseover="twosix()" class="circle hover" id="2006">
    <h2 id="date">2006</h2>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript function

```
function twosix(){
    document.getElementById("2006").style.opacity = "0";
}
```

the javascript file is called "timeline.js". I'm very confused on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So what does not work? I ran your code and it hides onmouseover

Comment: That function can only be called from within timeline.js

Comment: @AndrewBone I doubt that

Comment: @epascarello if it was twosix = function() {...} it would work

Comment: That is incorrect @AndrewBone

Comment: Check in the browser console to see if there is any javascript error. There might be some js error on your page or the js file path might be wrong. Actually, if you just want to change the opacity, just go for the css approach as @Chien_Khmt stated.

Comment: @epascarello try this with the console open and then change it to a variable https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/7n62r6u2/

Comment: @AndrewBone Because your fiddle is not correct!!! That is the only reason why it does not work. Your fiddle is NOT set up like the OPs. It is wrapped in an onload function so of course it is not global. OP does not have an onload or wrapper in what is shown. Change it to be in the head and magically it works fine.

Comment: @AndrewBone **epascarello** is correct on all points. [Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7n62r6u2/1/) that properly replicates how (order and scope) the OP is loading their JS. And it works!

Comment: Live and learn 

Answer (score 1):

So simple, you can use my class

```css
#div:hover
{
opacity:0
}
```

```html
<div id="div"> AAA</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 ways to do this

1. CSS
   As @Chien_Khmt said:

```css
.circle.hover:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle hover" id="2006">
  <h2 id="date">2006</h2>
</div>
```

2. Make the function a global function

To do this you save the function to a global variable like this

```js
twosix = function() {
  document.getElementById("2006").style.opacity = "0";
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="twosix()" class="circle hover" id="2006">
  <h2 id="date">2006</h2>
</div>
```

3. Use an event listener
   This means you don't have to make it a global variable

```js
document.getElementById("2006").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  twosix()
});

function twosix() {
  document.getElementById("2006").style.opacity = "0";
}
```

```html
<div class="circle hover" id="2006">
  <h2 id="date">2006</h2>
</div>
```

Of course, with 2 and 3 you need a mouse out event to make the div opaque again